# /ts/ vs /dz/: sono allofoni?

Tags: pronunciation

Mi potete spiegare...

- se sono allofoni
- altrimenti, se c'è una regola per distinguere quale pronuncia è quella corretta e dove posso consultare la pronuncia più adatta

Esempi di parole che mi danno questo dubbio: raga**zz**o/a, me**zz**o, spa**z**i, spa**zz**i, gra**z**ie, a**z**ienda, o**z**ono, roman**z**iere, for**z**a, **z**io, **z**an**z**ara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in italiano non sono allofoni, bensì fonemi distinti, anche se non ci sono molte coppie minime. Quella che si cita più di frequente è “razza” (/'raddza/), genere di pesci, e “razza” (/'rattsa/), presunta suddivisione dell'umanità.

Quanto al fonema previsto per ogni specifica parola, non c'è altro modo che cercarli su un dizionario. Per esempio, il Treccani (vedi la voce [“zanzara”](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/zanzara/)) indica con un puntino in alto (“żanżara”) la presenza del fonema /dz/ e con una normale “z” il fonema /ts/.